# Android camera2: how ho to get Image from a defined cameraId?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I use the following android code `CameraManager` service:

```
CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

String[] cameraIdList = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();
```

Now, I want to get the image from one of the `cameraIds` in this list in order to be able to execute the following code on this image:

```
ShortBuffer shortDepthBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().asShortBuffer();
```

How can I get this Image from a defined `cameraId` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is no fast and easy way to do this with the `Camera2` API. For a particular `cameraId` you need to:

1. Open camera device: `cameraManager.openCamera(...)`
2. Once the device is opened, use it to create capture session: `cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(...)`
3. Configure `ImageReader` for output and create capture request:: `cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(...)`
4. Use `captureSession` to process your capture request: `captureSession.capture(...)`
5. As the result you will obtain an `Image` from `ImageReader` that you have configured for capture output.

Therefore, for simple camera app I would suggest to [look](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) at `CameraX` instead.